# Is Class really only a blueprint for creating objects?

Tags: oop

It is said that in OOP - a class is a blueprint for creating an object.

But how does the fact that "static" is working without an instance gets along with this?

Is the "blueprint" only an over simplification of what Class really is?

And if so - how can we fix our mental model to understand both static and non static inside the same class?

Comment: Classes are objects too. Static members are just the members of the class itself. Think of a class as a factory object which can have its own state, in addition to the blueprint used to create instances.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: it is an over simplification. You can also have utility classes for which no instance is ever created.

Comment: Thanks. But can you please elaborate a bit more. 
Thinking in abstract manner - what IS a class

Answer (score 0):

> Is the "blueprint" only an over simplification of what Class really is?

Yes. But don't get me wrong here, the blueprint analogy is not bad because most of the time you are dealing with non-static members. I can't really think of a good way to explain static members well using this analogy. But I have a not-so-good way.

The objects you create using the blueprint has all the non-static members. So the non-static members describes the object that will be created by this blueprint. In contrast, static members describes the blueprint itself.

That's kind of a bad explanation, isn't it?

Static members don't belong to each individual object, but to the class itself. It's related to the class, but that member does not make sense to exist in each individual instance of the class.

You might think, when would I ever use such a thing? An example would be the singleton pattern. Here's one simple implementation in Java, but it compiles fine in C#:

```
class Earth {
    private static Earth instance = new Singleton();
    public static Earth getInstance() { return instance; }
    private Earth() {}
    // non-static members...
}
```

`instance` and `getInstance` does not exist on each individual object but rather on the class itself. Why? Because it only makes sense to have one of these `Earth` objects.

In addition, static members are also useful if you want utility methods. You can call them without creating an instance of a class. The `Math` class in both .NET and the JDK is an example of a class that is full of utiity methods.

Answer (score 0):

One ting at the beginning: OOP is a concept or a paradigm, while programming languages may fully or partly implement such concepts (and provide additional concepts besides those of OOP). C++ and C#, for example, still support primitive datatypes, which are no objects. In Smalltalk, on the other hand, even integer values are objects to which messages can be sent. And I think that even the definition what "OOP" concepts are is not clear (is multiple inheritance necessary to talk of OOP?)

Blueprint and `static` is actually not a contradiction, as `static` members can be seen as values/methods that are shared among all instances of the class. Hence, every object as "blueprint" of a class also has these static members available, yet not on its own. Further, one can see the class with its static member declarations also as a blueprint for the singleton `class` metaobject.

Take, for example, the following code in C++:

```cpp
class TestClass {
public:
    int instanceMember;
    static int classMember;
};

int TestClass::classMember;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    TestClass c1;
    c1.instanceMember = 5;
    c1.classMember = 3;

    TestClass c2;
    c2.instanceMember = 2;
    std::cout << "classMember of c2: " << c2.classMember;

    int accessMetaObject = TestClass::classMember;
    std::cout << "classMember accessed through metaobject: " << accessMetaObject;

    // Output:
    // classMember of c2: 3
    // classMember accessed through metaobject: 3
    return 0;
}
```

You see that you can access static member `c2.classMember` just like any other member, hence it is part of the "blueprint". The value, however, is shared among all instances, such that the value of `c2.classMember` is already set when creating the instance. Hope this helps a bit. Further, it shows that - as all instances share the same static members - you can access these members without any "real" instance through the (fictive) class metaobject, i.e. `TestClass::classMember`.

Note that some programming languages, like, for example, Smalltalk, explicitly distinguish between instance and class, and a `static` member is actually seen as a class member, i.e. a member of the respective `class`-metaobject.

Answer (score 0):

A better phrasing might be

> a class is a structure that *contains* a blueprint for objects, and also the capability to create such objects

Static methods are an extension to that structure, they have nothing to do with blueprints indeed. You could say that static methods are methods of the class object itself ("class methods"), one could even go so far as to say that the creation function ("constructor") is essentially a static method.

Depending on the particular language you are using, this distinction between blueprint and class object can be quite explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about this too much.  Humans tend to understand better by working with lots of examples, rather than reading explicit definitions (most concepts can't be boiled down to an exact definition)

You seem to understand the basic idea already:  classes can be blueprints for objects but can also contain static members that aren't tied to any particular object (but are perhaps used by all the objects that instantiate that class)

More tips:

All code in an OO language needs to be inside a class (unless you're typing it into a debugger or something else very temporary).  Therefore "class" is going to be a very generic term covering just about anything that can be done with code.

Note that a class can also be a blueprint for creating other *classes*.  Or it can just be handy place to keep a collection of static methods that might be used anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I wouldn't call a class a *blueprint* but an *archetype*.

Taken from [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/archetype):

> 1.1 An original which has been imitated; a prototype.

Also, taken from [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/archetype):

> The original pattern or model from which all things of the same kind
>   are copied or on which they are based; a model or first form;
>   prototype.

About class static members, I would say that they're just strangers within an object-oriented design or architecture. As you've already noted, *static members* aren't part of a class instance (i.e. *an object*), **but they're still useful**.

So, about your question:

> And if so - how can we fix our mental model to understand both static
>   and non static inside the same class?

...I would say that there's no mental fix. A class is the archetype of an object, and static members are part of no object.

Static class members treat classes like procedural modules: classes are turned into identifiers to group one or more static members.

In fact, check how more or less modern design patterns and paradigms tend to avoid static members: would you use statics if you would go the *dependency injection way*? **I doubt it**.

### In summary...

Definitively, static class member support is an implementation detail, it's not an object-oriented programming feature. There's a well-known language which doesn't implement **actual** statics:

```
class A {
   static doStuff() {}
}

// is
function A() {}
A.doStuff = function() {};
```

Yes, it's JavaScript! `static` modifier is just syntactic sugar of adding a property to a function, which is in turn an object...